# using a different wordpress function instead of the default one

Tags: php, wordpress

Hi I know this is probably an obvious one, but Im just wondering how do I use my own function that I would create in functions.php instead of the default one.

To explain what Ive done, I went into wp-includes/general-templates.php and changed alot of the code around that was in `get_calendar`.

But upon reading more online I realized that I shouldnt have done this as as soon as the user updates to a new wordpress these lines may be overwritten.

I kept a copy of the original general-templates.php file. So im wondering how do I implement my new updated function instead of the one in general-templates.php?

Thank you

Comment: http://venutip.com/content/right-way-override-theme-functions the add_action() function might help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WordPress provides two different means to override default function output: *pluggable functions* and *filters*.

### Pluggable Functions

A *pluggable* function (all of which live in `pluggable.php`), takes the following form:

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'some_function' ) ) {
    function some_function() {
        // function code goes here
    }
}
```

To override a pluggable function, simply define it in your own Plugin (or in your Theme's `functions.php` file, as applicable):

```
function some_function() {
    // Your custom code goes here
}
```

### Filters

A *filter* takes the following form:

```
function some_function() {
    // function code goes here
    return apply_filters( 'some_function', $output );
}
```

To override a filter, define a callback and add it to the filter:

```
function mytheme_filter_some_function( $output ) {
    // Define your custom output here
    return $output;
}
add_filter( 'some_function', 'mytheme_filter_some_function' );
```

### Specifically for `get_calendar()`

If you [look in source](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.4.2/wp-includes/general-template.php#L1270), you will see that the output for **[`get_calendar()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_calendar)** is passed through the **`get_calendar`** filter:

```
return apply_filters( 'get_calendar',  $calendar_output );
```

So you would simply write your own callback to modify `$calendar_output`, and hook it into `get_calendar`.

```
function mytheme_filter_get_calendar( $calendar_output ) {
    // Define your custom calendar output here
    $calendar_output = '';
    // Now return it
    return $calendar_output;
}
add_filter( 'get_calendar', 'mytheme_filter_get_calendar' );
```